# Does @Remote in Java EE 6 make private methods accessible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, remote-access, private-methods

Consider this code:

```
@Remote
public interface ISayHello {
    private void sayHello();
}
```

Will the `sayHello` method be accessible from the outside world or not?

Comment: you cannot define private methods in an interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to create private methods in an interface... They are all `public abstract` by default.

All public methods of your `@Remote` interface are EJB's business methods.

If you want to have some EJB methods not exposed to the outside world, either don't define them in the interface (in case you use local/remote business interfaces) or make them package private / protected / private (in case of no-interface view.)